# Change a single ytick value in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

There are a lot of similar questions on this topic but unfortunately, I still can't find a working solution to an annoying problem. I have the following plot:

```
ORDER = ['0%WT', '12%WT', '25%WT', '35%WT', '45%WT', '50%WT', '60%WT']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 5), dpi = 200)

sns.lineplot(x="Scenario", y="Clearing time", data=df, ax=ax)
sns.stripplot(x="Scenario", y="Clearing time", data=df, ax=ax, order=ORDER, alpha=0.5)
ax.grid(color='k', ls = '-.', lw = 0.25)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.ylabel('Critical clearing time [s]')
plt.show()
```

[image]

What I need to do is simply change the final value on the y-axis, which is currently 3, to '> 3'.

I tried explicitly labelling them like in the matplotlib docs but it would keep messing up the scale. I tried the following:

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(7), ('', '0.5', '1.0', '1.5', '2.0', '2.5', "> 3.0"))
```

and also:

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(7, step=0.5), ('', '0.5', '1.0', '1.5', '2.0', '2.5', "> 3.0"))
```

But can't get the desired result. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Does `ax.set_yticklabels(['0.5', '1.0', '1.5', '2.0', '2.5', "> 3.0"])` help you?

Comment: jeeeeez yes it does! with one minor change ax.set_yticklabels(['','0.5', '1.0', '1.5', '2.0', '2.5', "> 3.0"]). Thank you!!